Merge several text files into one text file
Folder has several text files and I want to merge them to Merge.txt when adding new files or editing files. Nothing advanced only copy the text and commit.
This should be super easy, but I can't find anyone who has a solution.
# This is a basic workflow to help you get started with Actions

name: CI

Controls when the workflow will run

on:

Triggers the workflow on push or pull request events but only for the "main" branch

push: branches: [ "main" ] 
pull_request: branches: [ "main" ]

Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab

workflow_dispatch:

A workflow run is made up of one or more jobs that can run sequentially or in parallel

jobs:

This workflow contains a single job called "build"

build: # The type of runner that the job will run on runs-on: ubuntu-latest

# Steps represent a sequence of tasks that will be executed as part of the job
steps:
  # Checks-out your repository under $GITHUB_WORKSPACE, so your job can access it
  - uses: actions/checkout@v4

  # Runs a single command using the runners shell
  - name: Merge TXT Files
    run: |
       find . -type f -name '*.txt' | while read fname; do


You shouldn't fundamentally change your question, by removing your code, after someone has answered it as you're removing context from the question. Also, you seem to have cut and pasted someone else's answer to your own answer post, and then accepted your own answer. That's not really how Stack Overflow works. Finally, if you do want to post clarifying questions/thanks or anything else that isn't part of your original question, or an original answer, they should go in comments.

I'm used to cleaning up your post so it's easier to find the answer.
The question has not changed, it is the same.
The answer was not complete, and I can't change another answer?
No it's not someone else's answer. That's my answer after I managed to solve it. So therefore I added a complete answer for others to use. Isn't that great? I can remove it if any admin would like.

# This is a basic workflow to help you get started with Actions

name: Merge multiple text files into a single file

# Controls when the workflow will run
on:
  # Triggers the workflow on push or pull request events but only for the "main" branch
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  workflow_dispatch:

# A workflow run is made up of one or more jobs that can run sequentially or in parallel
jobs:
  # This workflow contains a single job called "build"
  build:
    # The type of runner that the job will run on
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    # Steps represent a sequence of tasks that will be executed as part of the job
    steps:
      # Checks-out your repository under $GITHUB_WORKSPACE, so your job can access it
      - uses: actions/checkout@master
        with:
          persist-credentials: false # otherwise, the token used is the GITHUB_TOKEN, instead of your personal access token.
          fetch-depth: 0 # otherwise, there would be errors pushing refs to the destination repository.
        
      - name: Merge TXT Files in root folder
        run: |
          # Create and show list of files being processed
          echo "Files being processed:"
          find . -type f -name '*.txt' ! -name 'Merge.txt' -ls
          
          # Merge files and create Merge.txt
          find . -type f -name '*.txt' ! -name 'Merge.txt' -exec cat {} + > Merge.txt
          
          # Show the merged file was created
          echo -e "\nMerge.txt has been created:"
          ls -l Merge.txt
          
          # Show the content of Merge.txt
          echo -e "\nContent of Merge.txt:"
          cat Merge.txt

      - name: Commit files
        run: |
         git config --local user.email "41898282+github-actions[bot]@users.noreply.github.com"
         git config --local user.name "github-actions[bot]"
         git add Merge.txt
         git commit -a -m "Add changes"

      - name: Push changes
        uses: ad-m/github-push-action@master
        with: 
          github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          branch: ${{ github.ref }}


You can use something like this to merge multiple .txt files to a single Merge.txt file, if you want to commit that Merge.txt file then you can use other existing actions. I am going to show only the file merging example.
name: Merge multiple text files into a single file

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Merge TXT Files
        run: |
          # Create and show list of files being processed
          echo "Files being processed:"
          find . -type f -name '*.txt' ! -name 'Merge.txt' -ls
          
          # Merge files and create Merge.txt
          find . -type f -name '*.txt' ! -name 'Merge.txt' -exec cat {} + > Merge.txt
          
          # Show the merged file was created
          echo -e "\nMerge.txt has been created:"
          ls -l Merge.txt
          
          # Show the content of Merge.txt
          echo -e "\nContent of Merge.txt:"
          cat Merge.txt

Output:


It works! Thanks. But unfortunately the github_token: line does not work

Misunderstood how the TOKEN would be used in the code, so now it works.
